# Can we install Pytorch CUDA 11.3 when the system has CUDA 11.2

Tags: pytorch

I have cuda 11.2 in my PC and want to install PyTorch.
PyTorch has only mentions of CUDA10.2 and 11.3 in it's [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

Can I install torch==1.10.1+cu113 on my PC?
If not, how can I install PyTorch for CUDA11.2

I don't want to change my CUDA version as I have other applications using it.

Comment: Why not try it out to see what happens?

Comment: You have to install the CUDA version which Pytorch was built against. That is a non-negotiable requirement. Your two choices are to install a second CUDA runtime (CUDA 11.3)  for the prebuilt binary, or build your own Pytorch with CUDA 11.2

Answer (score 6):

I tried the one for 11.3 and so far it works fine w/ the GPU:

```
sudo pip install torch==1.12.1+cu113 torchvision==0.13.1+cu113 torchaudio==0.12.1 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio===0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

This worked but is not the latest version though

Answer (score 0):

Below worked fine in my case on `CUDA 11.2`

```
conda install -y pytorch==1.12.0 torchvision==0.13.0 -c pytorch
```

Comment: @NicoHaase this isn't a duplicate, since it uses a different control system (conda). This actually helped me.

Answer (score -1):

sure yes.

uninstall current cuda first
sudo /usr/local/cuda-X.Y/bin/cuda-uninstaller

and use dpkg uninstall libcudnn
ex: sudo dpkg --remove libcudnn7

then download runfile and install it also install corresponding libcudnn version